# В чем ошибка? Android Studio

Tags: java, android

```
SharedPreferences sPref;
final String SAVED_TEXT = "saved_text";
public void Check(View view) {
    sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    int progress = sPref.getInt(SAVED_TEXT, 2);
    if (progress==2) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Main6Activity.this, Main7Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if (progress==3) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Main6Activity.this, Main8Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if (progress==4) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Main6Activity.this, Main9Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if (progress==5) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Main6Activity.this, Main10Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if (progress==6) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Main6Activity.this, Main11Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if (progress==7) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Main6Activity.this, Main12Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if (progress==8) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Main6Activity.this, Main13Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if (progress==9) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Main6Activity.this, Main14Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if (progress==10) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Main6Activity.this, Main15Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if (progress==11) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Main6Activity.this, Main16Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if (progress==12) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Main6Activity.this, Main17Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if (progress==13) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Main6Activity.this, Main18Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if (progress==14) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Main6Activity.this, Main19Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
public void onClick(View view){
                sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
                ed.putInt(SAVED_TEXT, 2);
                ed.apply();
}
```

P.S. с пробелами и скобками все точно нормально.
При нажатии на кнопку в SAVED_TEXT должна сохраниться переменная 2, которая при нажатии на другую кнопку будет прочитана и будет проверена на то, какое это число, если полученная переменная равна например 2 тогда должна открыться другая активность, но этого не происходит.

Comment: Ошибка скорее всего в коде. Наверное у вас есть её описание от компилятора или из логов - приведите его, дополните вопрос описанием что не так. Иначе на ваш вопрос не ответить, т.к. собственно вопроса нет.

Comment: Я добавил описание.

Comment: Нужны ещё подробности. Убедитесь для начала в том, что методы в принципе вызываются. Например что-то выведя в логи. Также, это не будет работать если эти методы в разных активити.

Comment: Метод `Check(View view)` точно вызывается? Поставьте в метод код `Log.d("TEST", "run Check");` и проверьте в LogCat.

Comment: [Не в тему, но](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).